# One column value missing and no values are shown for entire row

Tags: oracle

[Below is expected results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vxhmq.gif) Below is code I work my actual out on , but if there is no procurement done then it returns a blank row

```
SELECT PRJ$Projects.project_id
    ,VW_QUOTE_SECTION_TOTALS.Quoted_section_total "Amount"
    ,VW_SECTION_TOTALS.Costed_section_total "Quoted Budget"
    ,(VW_QUOTE_SECTION_TOTALS.Quoted_section_total - VW_SECTION_TOTALS.Costed_section_total) "Gross Profit"
    ,ROUND(((VW_QUOTE_SECTION_TOTALS.Quoted_section_total - VW_SECTION_TOTALS.Costed_section_total) / VW_QUOTE_SECTION_TOTALS.Quoted_section_total) * 100) "GP %"
    ,ROUND(VW_PROC_SUM.total, 2) "Procured"
    ,(VW_SECTION_TOTALS.Costed_section_total - VW_PROC_SUM.total)
FROM PRJ$Projects
INNER JOIN prj$quotes ON prj$quotes.PROJECT_ID = PRJ$Projects.PROJECT_ID
    AND PRJ$Projects.QUOTE_TOTAL IS NOT NULL
INNER JOIN VW_PROC_SUM ON VW_PROC_SUM.PROJECT_ID = PRJ$Projects.PROJECT_ID
INNER JOIN prj$quote_sections ON prj$quote_sections.quote_id = prj$quotes.quote_id
INNER JOIN VW_SECTION_TOTALS ON VW_SECTION_TOTALS.QUOTE_SECTION_ID = prj$quote_sections.QUOTE_SECTION_ID
INNER JOIN VW_QUOTE_SECTION_TOTALS ON VW_QUOTE_SECTION_TOTALS.QUOTE_SECTION_ID = prj$quote_sections.QUOTE_SECTION_ID
    AND prj$quote_sections.quote_section_id = :P13_SECT_ID_H
```

Comment: The miracles of using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Just split your quey into small pieces and  try to find the error, We cant test your query without data or db schema Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.
 Try create a sample in http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Great thanks it shows procured but this part  (VW_SECTION_TOTALS.Costed_section_total - VW_PROC_SUM.total) "Available Budget" is also say null

Comment: add nvl:  (VW_SECTION_TOTALS.Costed_section_total - nvl(VW_PROC_SUM.total,0)). because 10-null=null.

Comment: Hello Thanks I had just done that